# Implementing binary cross entropy from scratch - inconsistent results in training a neural network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, numerical-stability, jax

I'm trying to implement and train a neural network using the JAX library and its little neural network submodule, "Stax". Since this library doesn't come with an implementation of binary cross entropy, I wrote my own:

```
def binary_cross_entropy(y_hat, y):
    bce = y * jnp.log(y_hat) + (1 - y) * jnp.log(1 - y_hat)
    return jnp.mean(-bce)
```

I implemented a simple neural network and trained it on MNIST, and started to get suspicious of some of the results I was getting. So I implemented the same setup in Keras, and I immediately got *wildly* different results! The same model, trained in the same way on the same data, was getting 90% training accuracy in Keras instead of around 50% in JAX.  Eventually I tracked down part of the issue to my naive implementation of cross-entropy, which is supposedly numerically unstable. Following [this](https://rafayak.medium.com/how-do-tensorflow-and-keras-implement-binary-classification-and-the-binary-cross-entropy-function-e9413826da7) post and [this](https://github.com/ddehueck/jax-loss/blob/master/jax_loss/classification.py) code I found, I wrote the following new version:

```
def binary_cross_entropy_stable(y_hat, y):
    y_hat = jnp.clip(y_hat, 0.000001, 0.9999999)
    logits = jnp.log(y_hat/(1 - y_hat))
    max_logit = jnp.clip(logits, 0, None)
    bces = logits - logits * y + max_logit + jnp.log(jnp.exp(-max_logit) + jnp.exp(-logits - max_logit))
    return jnp.mean(bces)
```

This works a little better. Now my JAX implementation gets up to 80% train accuracy, but that's still a lot less than the 90% Keras gets. What I want to know is **what is going on**?  Why are my two implementations not behaving the same way?

Below, I condensed my two implementations down to a single script. In this script, I implement the same model in JAX and in Keras. I initialize both with *the same weights*, and train them using full-batch gradient descent for 10 steps on 1000 datapoints from MNIST, the *same data* for each model. JAX finishes with 80% training accuracy, while Keras finishes with 90%. Specifically, I get this output:

```
Initial Keras accuracy: 0.4350000023841858
Initial JAX accuracy: 0.435
Final JAX accuracy: 0.792
Final Keras accuracy: 0.9089999794960022
JAX accuracy (Keras weights): 0.909
Keras accuracy (JAX weights): 0.7919999957084656
```

And actually, when I vary the conditions a little (using different random initial weights or a different training set), sometimes I get back the 50% JAX accuracy and 90% Keras accuracy.

I swap the weights at the end to verify that the weights obtained from training are indeed the issue, not something to do with the actual computation of the network predictions, or the way I calculate accuracy.

The code:

```
import numpy as np

import jax
from   jax import jit, grad
from   jax.experimental import stax, optimizers
import jax.numpy as jnp

import keras
import keras.datasets.mnist

def binary_cross_entropy(y_hat, y):
    bce = y * jnp.log(y_hat) + (1 - y) * jnp.log(1 - y_hat)
    return jnp.mean(-bce)

def binary_cross_entropy_stable(y_hat, y):
    y_hat = jnp.clip(y_hat, 0.000001, 0.9999999)
    logits = jnp.log(y_hat/(1 - y_hat))
    max_logit = jnp.clip(logits, 0, None)
    bces = logits - logits * y + max_logit + jnp.log(jnp.exp(-max_logit) + jnp.exp(-logits - max_logit))
    return jnp.mean(bces)

def binary_accuracy(y_hat, y):
    return jnp.mean((y_hat >= 1/2) == (y >= 1/2))

########################################
#                                      #
#          Create dataset              #
#                                      #
########################################

input_dimension = 784

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz")

xs = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
xs = xs.reshape((70000, 784))

ys = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])
ys = (ys >= 5).astype(np.float32)
ys = ys.reshape((70000, 1))

train_xs = xs[:1000]
train_ys = ys[:1000]

########################################
#                                      #
#           Create JAX model           #
#                                      #
########################################

jax_initializer, jax_model = stax.serial(
    stax.Dense(1000),
    stax.Relu,
    stax.Dense(1),
    stax.Sigmoid
)
rng_key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)

_, initial_jax_weights = jax_initializer(rng_key, (1, input_dimension))

########################################
#                                      #
#         Create Keras model           #
#                                      #
########################################

initial_keras_weights  = [*initial_jax_weights[0], *initial_jax_weights[2]]

keras_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

keras_model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
    loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

keras_model.build(input_shape=(1, input_dimension))

keras_model.set_weights(initial_keras_weights)

if __name__ == "__main__":

########################################
#                                      #
#      Compare untrained models        #
#                                      #
########################################

    initial_keras_predictions = keras_model.predict(train_xs, verbose=0)
    initial_jax_predictions   = jax_model(initial_jax_weights, train_xs)

    _, keras_initial_accuracy = keras_model.evaluate(train_xs, train_ys, verbose=0)
    jax_initial_accuracy = binary_accuracy(jax_model(initial_jax_weights, train_xs), train_ys)

    print("Initial Keras accuracy:", keras_initial_accuracy)
    print("Initial JAX accuracy:", jax_initial_accuracy)

########################################
#                                      #
#           Train JAX model            #
#                                      #
########################################
    
    L = jit(binary_cross_entropy_stable)
    gradL = jit(grad(lambda w, x, y: L(jax_model(w, x), y)))
    opt_init, opt_apply, get_params = optimizers.sgd(0.01)
    network_state = opt_init(initial_jax_weights)
    for _ in range(10):
        wT = get_params(network_state)
        gradient = gradL(wT, train_xs, train_ys)
        network_state = opt_apply(
            0,
            gradient,
            network_state
        )

    final_jax_weights = get_params(network_state)
    final_jax_training_predictions = jax_model(final_jax_weights, train_xs)
    final_jax_accuracy = binary_accuracy(final_jax_training_predictions, train_ys)

    print("Final JAX accuracy:", final_jax_accuracy)

########################################
#                                      #
#         Train Keras model            #
#                                      #
########################################

    for _ in range(10):
        keras_model.fit(
            train_xs,
            train_ys,
            epochs=1,
            batch_size=1000,
            verbose=0
        )

    final_keras_loss, final_keras_accuracy = keras_model.evaluate(train_xs, train_ys, verbose=0)

    print("Final Keras accuracy:", final_keras_accuracy)

########################################
#                                      #
#            Swap weights              #
#                                      #
########################################

    final_keras_weights = keras_model.get_weights()
    final_keras_weights_in_jax_format = [
        (final_keras_weights[0], final_keras_weights[1]),
        tuple(),
        (final_keras_weights[2], final_keras_weights[3]),
        tuple()
    ]
    jax_accuracy_with_keras_weights = binary_accuracy(
        jax_model(final_keras_weights_in_jax_format, train_xs),
        train_ys
    )
    print("JAX accuracy (Keras weights):", jax_accuracy_with_keras_weights)

    final_jax_weights_in_keras_format = [*final_jax_weights[0], *final_jax_weights[2]]
    keras_model.set_weights(final_jax_weights_in_keras_format)
    _, keras_accuracy_with_jax_weights = keras_model.evaluate(train_xs, train_ys, verbose=0)
    print("Keras accuracy (JAX weights):", keras_accuracy_with_jax_weights)
```

Try changing the PRNG seed at line 57 to a value other than `0` to run the experiment using different initial weights.

Answer (score 2):

Your `binary_cross_entropy_stable` function does not match the output of `keras.binary_crossentropy`; for example:

```py
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

print(keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(x, y))
# tf.Tensor(0.8134677734043875, shape=(), dtype=float64)

print(binary_cross_entropy_stable(x, y))
# 0.9781515
```

That is where I would start if you're trying to exactly duplicate the model.

You can view the source of the keras loss function here: [keras/losses.py#L1765-L1810](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a5a6a53eceb4bb0957fcbe577f56941ae8062d8f/keras/losses.py#L1765-L1810), with the main part of the implementation here: [keras/backend.py#L4972-L5017](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a5a6a53eceb4bb0957fcbe577f56941ae8062d8f/keras/backend.py#L4972-L5017)

One detail: it appears that with a sigmoid activation function, Keras re-uses some cached logits to compute the binary cross entropy while avoiding problematic values: [keras/backend.py#L4988-L4997](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a5a6a53eceb4bb0957fcbe577f56941ae8062d8f/keras/backend.py#L4988-L4997). I'm not sure how to easily replicate that behavior using JAX & stax.

Comment: I'd noticed these discrepancies before. That's quite a large one - often it's accurate to about two decimal places. Since it's usually accurate enough, I ignored it, since any two different implementations of a function involving floating points are going to give slightly different values anyway. Interesting that the Keras code doesn't convert to logits first. I rewrote my loss function to be pretty much exactly like the Keras one and I'm still getting (slightly) different loss values, and still getting (wildly) different training behavior.

Comment: Nevermind, there's actually an issue with your test code. Keras's loss functions expect their arguments in the *opposite* order to mind: target values, then predictions. If you swap `x` and `y` in your call to Keras's loss function, you should be fine. That's not relevant to the issue in my code in the question though, since Keras calls its loss functions internally.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I missed that. I'm not sure what the difference is, then. Perhaps keras is doing more evaluations under the hood: if you bump the JAX iterations up, you get to an accuracy similar to that of the keras model.

Comment: Do you? Even going up to 1000 iterations for JAX, I can't get past about 50% accuracy (this is using the updated loss function, the one based on Keras's code).

Comment: Using your code as written but changing `10` to `100` in the JAX loop, I see a final JAX accuracy of `0.946`.

Comment: You're right, so do I. Although only for certain starting seeds, perhaps 25% of the ones I tried. Meanwhile, Keras seems to nail 90%+ accuracy every time, although perhaps that doesn't discount your theory depending on what exactly it's doing under the hood. Would you mind trying a few other initializations?